# What framework does forecast io use to "download" an app when you visit their website on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios

If you visit forecast.io from an iPhone, they ask you to download their app (really you just add to homescreen, and it looks like an actual app). I think it's some js framework. Anyone know what it is called?

Comment: did you see this http://blog.forecast.io/its-not-a-web-app-its-an-app-you-install-from-the-web/

Answer (score 4):

We don't use a framework, because it's pretty straightforward:

First, when the page loads we look to see if the `window.navigator.standalone` property is set. Mobile Safari sets this to true if the app has been launched from the homescreen. If it's not, we display the installation screen (which is just a big div that covers the page).

Next, we add some meta tags in the HTML, which tell Mobile Safari to hide the browser chrome (buttons, etc), sets a homescreen icon, etc. You can find all about them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

Comment: Are you from Forecast? If so, you should state so in your post to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yup, I'm from Forecast. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @AdamGrossman what framework forecast.io uses for the mobile web app for the components, like left panel and acccordions ?